# Is there any way to perform a sort of null coalesce on a property in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, null-coalescing-operator

I'm not quite sure how to phrase this question but the scenario is as follows:

Say I have the following class:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

I know you can null coalesce the containing class:

```
SampleClass newSampleClass = possibleNullSampleClass ?? notNullSampleClass;
```

Is there any way to perform a sort of null coalesce on the property so I don't have to do this:

```
int? num = sampleClass != null ? new int?(sampleClass.Number) : 5;
```

It seems like it would be very useful to have something like a `???` operator to perform this check so I could do:

```
int? num = sampleClass.Number ??? 5;
```

Is anything like that possible in C#?

Comment: Is there a name or term for this sort of operation? Is it planned for any future versions of C#? It seems like it would be very nice to have.

Comment: This is typically called the "existential operator" and is found in Coffeescript and a handful of other languages. It is typically represented as `?.` eg `SampleClass?.Number`

Comment: A related concept is also the null object pattern. For example, in Objective-C, you can simply write the equivalent to sampleClass.Number, and it will not throw an exception - you'll get a definite value back.

Comment: While I'm not sure what Objective-C has to do with the null object pattern, I think its a better solution than null checking as per the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently there is no such an operator. But in C# 6 "safe-navigation" operator will appear and you'll be able to write

```
int number = sampleClass?.Number;
```

This code won't fail with NullRef even if `sampleClass` equals `null`. For now you can use the following extension method that extracts value from an object and encapsulates null-check:

```
public static TResult Maybe<TSource, TResult>(
    this TSource source, Func<TSource, TResult> produceResult, Func<TResult> produceDefault)
    where TSource : class
{
    return source == null ? produceDefault() : produceResult(source);
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
int numberOrFive = sampleClass.Maybe(c => c.Number, () => 5);
```

Comment: Very cool, I look forward to C# 6. I like this maybe extension method as well but I'm not sure I want to increase clutter with extension methods.

Comment: Sometimes extension methods helps to write more short and declarative code. You can compare two methods that do the same but written in different styles: https://gist.github.com/takemyoxygen/6501402

Answer (score 3):

There is no existing operator to do that.  You have shown one perfectly acceptable way of handling the problem.

If you wanted, you could wrap the logic in a method, but I'm not sure if that'd actually be worth the effort or not:

```
public static TResult Access<TSource, TResult>(
    TSource obj, Func<TSource, TResult> selector, TResult defaultIfNull)
    where TSource : class
{
    if (obj == null)
        return defaultIfNull;
    else
        return selector(obj);
}
```

---

```
SampleClass sampleClass = null;
int num = Access(sampleClass, s => s.Number, 5);
```

(If you wanted, you could consider making that an extension method as well, although I personally am wary of extension methods on all classes.  Also consider other names, such as `Use`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to propose a modification of Servy's post. I think his method would prove useful if it could handle the general case, where there can be a null anywhere up the object chain.

```
public static TResult Access<TSource, TResult>(
   TSource obj, Func<TSource, TResult> selector, TResult defaultIfNull)
   where TSource : class
{
    TResult result;
    try
    {
        result = selector(obj);
    }
    catch ( NullReferenceException)
    {
        result = defaultIfNull;
    }

    return result;

}
```

This way if you are trying to access
        ZipCode = Customer.Address.ZipCode;

You are protected if either Customer or Address is null

Comment: You should not use exceptions for control flow.  If you have a chain of objects you'd simply chain the calls to this method for each level, to maintain safety through the entire depth.  That said; having a call chain like that in which all of the values could be `null` is a situation you generally shouldn't be putting yourself in to begin with; you're probably using `null` when you shouldn't be.

Comment: Can propose another way to solve the issue of preventing nullreference issues up and down the object reference without trapping the exception?

Comment: Sure, as I said, you chain the calls to this method.

Comment: Null Object Pattern - but it depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Chaining the calls is going to make pretty ugly code:

var zip = Access(Customer, c => Access(c.Address, a => a.ZipCode,"00000"), "00000") 

I think readability trumps dogmatic aversion to catching exceptions.

Comment: Again, see my first comment.  If you're putting yourself in that position, you almost certainly have a design problem.  For example, in that case `Address` shouldn't ever be null, so you shouldn't need to code for it being null.

Comment: He could be calling code written by a third party and has no control over how it's designed. I've run into this exact situation myself. Probably best that we agree to disagree on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in C#. You need to explicitly test for nullity:

```
MyWidget x ;

int? v = x == null ?  (int?)x.SomeProperty : (int?) null ;
```

If you really think it would be useful, you could log your suggestion at Microsoft Connect:

```
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio
```

I'm willing to be that they thought about it and decided it wasn't sufficiently useful to build into the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do this:

```
var x = (myObject ?? DefaultObject).Field;
```

And this...

```
var x = (myObject == null) ? myObject.Field : defaultValue;
```

Comment: This assumes that you have a `DefaultObject` that will be both not null and have a sensible default value for the given field.  You're not creating such an object, which is where the work lies.  In some cases you may also not be in a position where you're *able* to construct an object, affect what its field value will return, or creating an instance could be prohibitively expensive.

Comment: None of which is a requirement in the question. If those things are important, you gotta mention it. I do the above quite often. The accepted answer with the extension method is LESS READABLE than this.

Comment: 1) You still need to construct the object regardless, giving the solution a false sense of terseness 2) You're asserting it as a solution for the *general case*, not *one specific case*, as such you'd need to be prepared for all of those problems to come up at some point or another.